# Why does my website has extra space in its right corner only in its mobile version?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vercel

So I have created a website(deployed on Vercel) for practice and built it responsive by having breakpoints for different screen sizes. But now, when I see the same website's dashboard page on my mobile, I see some extra unwanted space in its right-top corner and in its index page's desktop view; the footer is, for some reason floating above the bottom of the screen. I have pictures below of [desktop view of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Qps.png) and [dashboard page as shown in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFvHQ.png) and [as shown in Chrome Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUEhO.jpg).
I have built it using React and Tailwind CSS. My website's link is

- Dashboard link - https://build2-eight.vercel.app/dashboard
- Index Page - https://build2-eight.vercel.app/

And in my development server, neither of the issues were encountered.
The code is:-

```
/* Index.css custom tailwind classes */
@layer components{
    .cardMainPage{
        box-shadow:0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0,0.32);
        @apply flex flex-col items-center justify-start text-2xl gap-5 p-2 py-3 rounded-md bg-white;
    }
    .Icons{
        @apply bg-[#aff0cc] rounded-full h-16 md:h-8 w-16 md:w-8 flex flex-row justify-center items-center cursor-pointer hover:bg-white;
    }
    .HeaderIcons{
        @apply bg-[#aff0cc] p-2 h-8 w-8 rounded-sm hover:bg-white cursor-pointer;
    }
}
```

React Code : -

```
 /* Footer React code */
   import React from 'react';
   
    export default function Footer() {
      return (
        <div className='bg-[#5cdb95] text-[#05386b] w-full text-md flex items-center justify-center'>
            <div className='text-center'>
                Made with <b className='text-red-600 text-lg'>&hearts;</b> by <a href="/" className=' underline hover:no-underline'>Soumya Deep Sarkar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Dashboard code->

```
/* Dashboard page code */
import React from "react";
import Header from "../header/index";
import Footer from "../footer/index";
import { GrBitcoin, GrGamepad } from "react-icons/gr";
import { SiCodingninjas } from "react-icons/si";
import { FiSearch } from "react-icons/fi";
import { FcSettings, FcBusinessman } from "react-icons/fc";
import { IoMdNotifications } from "react-icons/io";
import {GrChat} from "react-icons/gr"

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
      <Header />
      <div className="flex flex-row h-full">
        <div
          id="left-side-menu"
          className="p-2 px-1 bg-back py-4 flex justify-between h-full flex-col"
        >
          <div className=" flex flex-col gap-3">
            <span className="Icons">
              <GrBitcoin />
            </span>
            <span className="Icons">
              <GrGamepad />
            </span>
            <span className="Icons">
              <SiCodingninjas />
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
            <span className="Icons">
              <FcSettings />
            </span>
            <span className="Icons">
                <FcBusinessman/>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center-menu" className="flex flex-col w-full">
            <div className="bg-[#20d876] w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center px-4">
                <span className="HeaderIcons my-1"><IoMdNotifications className="text-yellow-500"/></span>
                <form className="w-full flex flex-row items-center justify-center p-1">
                    <span className="relative flex items-center">
                        <input type="text" className="border-2 px-2 rounded-md border-text "/>
                        <span className="absolute right-1 cursor-text"><FiSearch/></span>
                    </span>
                </form>
                <span className="HeaderIcons"><GrChat className="text-yellow-500"/></span>        
                <div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-side-menu"></div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The textbox(search one) is causing the issue in case of the dashboard header. To fix it I just have to define its width to 100% and it worked out.
Regarding the footer issue. I had to define the minimum height of the window. So I set min height to 100vh.
In tailwind css, for the dashboard header I just put w-full in the className attribute and for the footer I put min-h-screen in the parent div.